# Specific group of the dataset without cycles

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset with columns Id, Week and Money.

```
Id Week Money 
1  1    18  
2  1    19
3  1    21
4  1    25
1  2    27 
3  2    29 
2  2    40
```

I want to compare ine ID with another during one week. So on the output I want to get something like this:

```
Id1 Id2 Week Money1 Money2 
1    2    1    18   19
1    3    1    18   21
1    4    1    18   25 
2    1    1    19   18
2    3    1    19   21
2    4    1    19   25
.....
3    1    2    29   27
3    2    2    29   40
```

After that I would like to get each group and do some operations. For example, I want to take  first group

```
Id1 Id2 Week Money1 Money2 
1    2    1    18   19
1    3    1    18   21
1    4    1    18   25
```

and pass to some_func() columns "Money1", "Money2".
I can do that with the for loops and df.loc, but the amount of data that I have is very big, so it takes a lot of time. Can I do it faster?

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use cross join with [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) by `Week` column, then change order of columns of `list`:

```
df = df.merge(df, on='Week', suffixes=('1','2'))[['Id1','Id2','Week','Money1','Money2']]
print (df)
    Id1  Id2  Week  Money1  Money2
0     1    1     1      18      18
1     1    2     1      18      19
2     1    3     1      18      21
3     1    4     1      18      25
4     2    1     1      19      18
5     2    2     1      19      19
6     2    3     1      19      21
7     2    4     1      19      25
8     3    1     1      21      18
9     3    2     1      21      19
10    3    3     1      21      21
11    3    4     1      21      25
12    4    1     1      25      18
13    4    2     1      25      19
14    4    3     1      25      21
15    4    4     1      25      25
16    1    1     2      27      27
17    1    3     2      27      29
18    1    2     2      27      40
19    3    1     2      29      27
20    3    3     2      29      29
21    3    2     2      29      40
22    2    1     2      40      27
23    2    3     2      40      29
24    2    2     2      40      40
```

Then use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
def func(x):
    print (x)
    #e.g. some custom function
    x['new'] = (x['Id1'] > x['Id2']).sum()
    return x

df = df.groupby(['Id1','Week','Money1']).apply(func)
```